# Using Multiple Size Classes

Tags: ios, size-classes

So I've built this app and the layout is so that it requires me to use two size classes:

1) wCompact hAny

2) wCompact hRegular

All the alignments and all that is great and this *should* be giving a smooth, consistent display across all devices. However, it seems that the 2nd size class is overriding the 1st one in all situations. I only want number 2 to fire up on 6+, but it's doing so on 6 and 5s as well.

How can I fix this? It's really holding me up on here.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your app suport ipad also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First size classes you are using is for iPhone 4,iPhone5s and iPhone 6 for Portrait and landscape .

The Second size classes you are using is for all iPhone devices in  portrait mode only.which means obviously they are overriding each other.

Use only second layout for all iPhone devices in portrait mode. and if you want to use size classes for landscape mode wAny hCompact.

For more  details aboout size classes follow this link.

[Size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)